# how can I create an air-gapped printer?

Tags: printer

Are there any cheap printers on the market that do not have any networking and can accept print jobs via USB stick?

Or, how can I  physically remove the wifi functionality of a modern printer?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for product recommendations is off-topic, as is  instructions for modifying a theoretical printer.  But there shouldn't be a problem finding a printer without WiFi capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you seek is not particularly sought after, but there are at least a couple of ways of gaining the functionality.

The first is to get a moderately-high end printer (most likely an MFC printer) with print from USB functionality, and simply do not plug it in to Ethernet, WIFI or USB to PC.  Use the print from USB functionality built into it.

The other solution would be to get a USB only printer and then use a low end computer - something like a Raspberry Pi might do to read the USB stick and print it's contents. Don't network the Raspberry PI.